# How do I set a PHP cookie to expire in the future

Tags: php, cookies

I am at a loss.

When I set cookies with the code below...

```
$thisUser = $player['userID'];
$thisUserName = $player['username'];

setcookie("userID", $thisUser, time()+3600, "/","", 0);
setcookie("username", $thisUserName, time()+3600, "/","", 0);

setcookie("testcookie", "TEST VALUE", time() + 3600, "/", "", 0);
```

For whatever reason, the testcookie sets the expiration to an hour later.  The other 2 do not set the expire, just says when browser session closes. The cookies get set with the appropriate values, except expire.  What am I missing?

I have session_start(); at the beginning of the page.

Comment: Have You tried that with different browsers? The problem might be on the other side. I suppose.

Comment: You're taking current time and adding an hour to it (3600 seconds = 1 hour). What is the exact issue you're having?

Comment: Based on the above code, you have everything correct. Seems like you are setting domain and secure flag without a need to do so.

Comment: `$thisUser` and `$thisUserName` are string/int variables?

Comment: It's doing the same thing in all browsers (IE, FireFox, Chrome). The userID and username cookies won't set the expire parameter. They just say it expires when the Browsing Session Ends. The testcookie cookie, has the expire set to 1 hour. I need to be able to set cookies to expire in the future to a value of my setting.

Comment: Andrés, yes they are. $thisUser is an INT and $thisUserName is a string

Comment: Be careful with strings in cookies' contents. Not all string formats are working with cookies.

Comment: But why if I hard set the cookie value "TEST VALUE" the expire parameter sets. But when I use a variable, it doesn't.

Comment: Looks like a collision to me, there are probably other apps under the same domain that set cookies with these names.

Comment: Narf, I do not have any other cookies storing on this domain.  This is the first page that I am attempting to use them.